Why can't we swap $5 \times 3 + 2 \times 6$ to be $5 \times 3 \times 6 + 2$
I'm teaching Order of Operations and a pupil had answered $5 \times 3 + 2 \times 6$ to be
$$15 + 2 \times 6
= 15 \times 6 + 2 
= 90 + 2 = 92 $$
The pupil argued that different multiplications can be done in any order, and that multiplication should be done before addition, as I had taught them. I couldn't really articulate what was inherently wrong about what they had done, other than "you need to group your calculations on either side of the + sign".
It was honestly something I had never given much thought to before. It's the sort of thing you just do and know as an experienced mathematician. I wasn't able to give a satisfactory answer. I would like to give a more thorough explanation to my whole class in the next lesson. Any advice?
Basically, what is wrong with swapping $a +2$ and $\times 6$ in a calculation, when the $\times 6$ is carried out first regardless? Or, what rule is in place to ensure we don't do this?
I'm a little embarrassed even having to post this, it's funny how sometimes the more basic concepts are the hardest to explain - all help appreciated!

You do not apply the same oprations : In one case , you multiply $5\cdot 3$ with $6$ , in the other case , you multiply $2$ with $6$.

I don't understand your question.  The expression $5\times 3 + 2\times 6$ is to be interpreted as $(5\times 3)+(2\times 6)$.  This is nothing like $((5\times 3)\times 6)+2$

I of course understand the difference between the two questions and answers, but was more asking what rule is applied to ensure that these are not interchanged by pupils accidentally. I had not yet introduced pupils to the idea of using brackets, so maybe that is something I should discuss first before providing them with questions like this.

It's not an explicit rule, but it's a bit like asking, why can't I just rearrange the words in a sentence however I want? Because doing so often changes the meaning or gives something nonsensical. In some specific cases you get the same meaning/calculation, but not in general.

Think about turning everything into sums. Then $5\times 3 = 5+5+5$ and $(5\times 3) \times 6=5\times 3 + ...+5\times 3 = 5+5+5+...5+5+5$.

I've encountered this confusion with students occasionally, and I suspect they have viewed the sequence as starting with a $5$, then applying the operations "times $3$", "plus $2$", "times $6$". So naturally the question arises, if multiplication takes precedence over addition, why don't we do the multiplications first, and then the addition last? And one explanation is that the operations are not unary modifications to $5$. We could write our expressions that way, but we don't. The way we do write them requires that we interpret the additions and multiplications as binary operators.

It is very misleading to say "you do multiplication first". Arithmetic precedence — confusingly called "order of operation" — has nothing to do with order of computation! It should be more accurately described as how strongly the operators bind with their operands. In $2 \times 3 + 4$, $\times$ binds more strongly, so we get $(2 \times 3) + 4$, which is in reality a tree-like structure, but we are forced to write it in a line on paper. We can, in fact, compute in any order, as long as there is a valid rule applicable. For example, $0 \times (3^4 + 5 \times 7)$ can be computed to be zero in one step, since it is a valid rule that zero times anything is zero. In the case $2 \times 3 + 4$, the only valid rule is to multiply $2 \times 3 = 6$, because we don't have a rule to add something that is not a numeral. Therefore we must compute the multiplication first, but this is purely coincidental and dependent on the set of valid rules.
Similarly, addition and subtraction operate "from left to right" is a statement about the associativity, not the order of computation. There are some operators with associativity from right to left, such as the logical implication $a \to b \to c$, or, depending on convention, the textual exponentiation operator $a \hat{} b \hat{} c$.
The rules that govern precedence and associativity is used in parsing, while the rules that govern computation is used in rewriting. You can follow the links for a more technical explanation. I can't really suggest how to tell your students about these though, you can ask on the math educators stack exchange to see if you get more professional advice.

I came up with an intuitive way of thinking about those expressions for myself not much different from Trebor's.
Addition and subtraction separate expressions, multiplication binds them together. Further, fundamentally, there is no subtraction or division, just adding the additive inverse or multiplying by the multiplicative inverse(reciprocal), respectively. Parentheses and exponentiation are other binders that take precedence.
So your student is trying to separate entities that should be bound together and can't pass through the separating plus sign that keeps the bounded expressions apart. Once everything is consistently reckoned in terms of strictly multiplication and addition, commutativity can be used to re-arrange terms since both operations are commutative. If given $a/b$ it's wrong to calculate $b/a$. But $a/b=a \cdot (1/b)=(1/b)\cdot a$.

I'm a teacher too. I have written about this before (on Mastodon). The example I commonly use is I have 1 2 litre bottle of milk, and 4 3 litre bottles of milk - how many litres do I have? That's easy enough for students to count up and arrive at 2+3+3+3+3=14 litres.
Now we can also write that as 2+3x4, so therefore we know that has to equal 14. But if you do addition first you get 20, so that's wrong!
And from the way I've written that you can easily see that multiplication is actually shorthand for addition - i.e. 3x4=3+3+3+3 - which is the precise reason you have to do it first. You have to expand your shorthand additions (multiplication) before you can do the addition, or you get the wrong answer.
Similarly, exponents are shorthand for multiplication - i.e. a²=axa - and so have to be done before multiplication... which has to be done before addition. And since addition and subtraction are the opposite of each other, as are multiplication and division, and brackets signify what always has to be done first, welcome to we've just proved the order of operations rules - BEDMAS. :-)
P.S. "The pupil argued that different multiplications can be done in any order"
TL;DR you can with ...x2x6, but not with ...+2x6.
That's true to a degree, but it's also important to remember that multiplication is a binary operator. i.e. not only is it associated with the term following it, but also the term preceding it. When your student did 15+2×6=15×6+2 they've changed the term on the left of the multiply, thus changing the answer. If there's only multiplies, such as 1x15x2x6, then yes, you can do 1x2x6x15, or 1x6x2x15, etc., and still get the same answer. But given the 2 is preceded by a +, not an x (same goes for the 15), then it changes the answer if you only move the x6

It is simple:

$15 + 2\times 6$ means (is an abbreviation of) $15 + (2\times 6)$, which is $15 + 12 = 27$, but

$15\times 6 + 2$ means $(15\times 6) + 2$, which is $92$.


If the student thinks that the two are equal, it is the student who needs to prove it. But obviously there can be no valid proof/justification.

There is a proof. See my answer

@donaldp, you proved that $27 = 92$?

Oh! Ha ha ha! No, I missed that bit I thought you meant there was no proof of as to why multiplication has to be done before addition - THAT'S what I proved. I guess I'm just a bit overjaded at this point with people saying there's no proof for the order of operations when there absolutely is. As you were :-)

@donaldp, well, about "multiplication before addition," I think I explained that.
